# Networked Ruby on Rails URL/Address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I have created an app with a Ruby on Rails backend and a VueJS frontend. I have successfully created the desktop version of the app, but I am now testing and tweaking the mobile version to verify cross compatibility.

The challenge that I am confronted with is that I can access the VueJS portion of my app via the local IP address that the VueJS server provides (http://10.0.0.163:8080), but I have no such networked IP address for the Ruby on Rails server.

As such, my app will appear, but it does not function 100%, as the VueJS app cannot reference the Ruby on Rails address (http://localhost:3000) while being viewed on another networked device.

Does anyone know of a way to change the settings so that I can remotely access the Ruby on Rails server from a networked VueJS address?

If anyone has any resources, it would be of great assistance.

Thank you,

DD

Comment: Using ifconfig get your system's IP address. Now you can run rails server on that IP `rails s -b your ip -p desired port`. Now you should be to connect but make sure you mobile and system are communicating over same network. Probably same wifi.

Comment: You can also use a tunnel such as NGrok which will give you a public IP to your localhost. This can be accessed by a device on any network.

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate your help!